# Static key word in managing thread synchronization - Java

Tags: java

I got a question regarding code posted below. Why do I need to put the word "static" in front of declaration of SumArray object to make this code run properly? Why doesn't synchronized method guarantee (by its own) to be called for one thread at a time? Indeed, If I remove the "static" word, then the SumArray method will be called interchangeable by 2 threads. Nevertheless, the sums for boths threads will be correct.

```
class SumArray {
    private int sum;

    synchronized int sumArray(int numbers[]) {
        sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            sum += numbers[i];
            System.out.println("Current Sum for " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " equals " + sum);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread has been stopped");
            }

        }
        return sum;
    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    int a[];
    int ans;
    static SumArray sa = new SumArray();

    MyThread(String name, int numbers[]) {
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        t.start();
        a = numbers;
    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println(t.getName() + " is starting.");
        ans = sa.sumArray(a);

        System.out.println("Final Sum for " + t.getName() + " equals " + ans);
        System.out.println(t.getName() + " has been finished.");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        new MyThread("Thread 1", a);
        new MyThread("Thread 2", a);
    }
}
```

The example result for code with `static SumArray sa = new SumArray();`

```
Thread 2 is starting.
Thread 1 is starting.
Current Sum for Thread 2 equals 1
Current Sum for Thread 2 equals 3
Current Sum for Thread 2 equals 6
Current Sum for Thread 2 equals 10
Current Sum for Thread 2 equals 15
Current Sum for Thread 1 equals 1
Final Sum for Thread 2 equals 15
Thread 2 has been finished.
Current Sum for Thread 1 equals 3
Current Sum for Thread 1 equals 6
Current Sum for Thread 1 equals 10
Current Sum for Thread 1 equals 15
Final Sum for Thread 1 equals 15
Thread 1 has been finished.
```

And the result with `SumArray sa = new SumArray();`

```
Thread 2 is starting.
Thread 1 is starting.
Current Sum for Thread 2 equals 1
Current Sum for Thread 1 equals 1
Current Sum for Thread 1 equals 3
Current Sum for Thread 2 equals 3
Current Sum for Thread 2 equals 6
Current Sum for Thread 1 equals 6
Current Sum for Thread 1 equals 10
Current Sum for Thread 2 equals 10
Current Sum for Thread 2 equals 15
Current Sum for Thread 1 equals 15
Final Sum for Thread 2 equals 15
Thread 2 has been finished.
Final Sum for Thread 1 equals 15
Thread 1 has been finished.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because inside thread you create a new object and it has its own sumArray method. When it is static there is only one  sumArray function through whole jvm that belongs to the class, not to the object

Comment: Ok, feel free to correct me If I didn't caught something on properly. But with word "static" in code before SumArray we just make sure that ONLY one object of that type is created for all threads (in this case for 2 threads). That implicates that only one method (called also SumArray) can be called for one thread(the first one), because of "synchronized" word in front of method name until it finishes. Then goes the execution of this method for next Thread etc.

Comment: Without the static word we are able to construct 2 SumArrays objects and so Threads can run interchangeable calling method for that separate objects. However the results are correct - it is because that both threads operate on their own objects->methods.

Comment: with static we make sure that all threads are calling same method. By synchronized we make sure only one method has access to that one method. Others will have to wait until the thread that holds the lock is done with it

Comment: @Ares02 Think like this. You enter a room which has only a single key. Now until you come out of it, no one else can enter that room. But what happens if there were two seperate rooms for both of you? Other person will enter his room, while you'll enter yours. Key is to make sure you have created only 1 room for both.

Comment: "By synchronized we make sure only one method has access to that one method." I've a guess you meant "one THREAD has access to that one method" ;)

Comment: Yea, but is it necessary?  I mean, with only synchronized method, the results are correct too. And methinks that without static the application excecution  ends faster. Because in the meantime when the thread one is asleep, the second one can do his job and vice versa.

Comment: If its not resource heavy and not many threads are accesing it, yes  I think it is not necessary.

Comment: Do you mind marking it as correct answer. You are welcome